# Python - Convert list of 2D co-ordinate pairs to 2 lists of X and Y components

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, coordinates

I have a string which contains several pairs of 2D co-ordinate points as follows:

```
input = '(1, 2), (3, 5.5), (7, -2), (16, 0), (5, 3)'
```

I want to take this string and end up with two lists, named X and Y which contain the X and Y co-ordinates respectively of the points in the string (in their original order):

outputs:

```
X = ['1', '3', '7', '16', '5']

Y = ['2', '5.5', '-2', '0', '3']
```

How can I do this using Python 3?

Comment: Don't name variables `input`.  It overrides a builtin

Comment: In my program I didn't name it input, I just did it here to show that is the kind of input that the program will take.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use **`zip`** with [**`ast.literal_eval`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
s = '(1, 2), (3, 5.5), (7, -2), (16, 0), (5, 3)'
x, y = zip(*ast.literal_eval(s))

x
(1, 3, 7, 16, 5)

y
(2, 5.5, -2, 0, 3)
```

If you are set on the output being a list, you can use:

```
x, y = map(list, zip(*ast.literal_eval(s)))
```

Comment: @OP, note the necessary `import ast`

Comment: Glad to help, happy programming!